# Nested recursions

Tags: ocaml

Let's assume we have one check function:

```
let check x y = if (y mod x) = 0 then true else false;;
```

Then for any given couple a b, I would like to iterate to find the couple i j that would satisfy:  1 < i <= a AND  1 < j <= b and check i j = true.
I am iterating i downto 1 and j (up)to b.

```
let g (x, y) = 
  let rec gf i j = 
    if check i j then (i, j) 
    else gs i j 
  and gs i j = 
    if check i j then (i, j) 
    else if j <= y then gs i (j + 1) 
    else if i > 1 then gf (i - 1) j 
    else (-1, -1)
  in 
  (gf x 1 && gs x 1);;
```

But I get error:

```
Error: This expression has type int * int
       but an expression was expected of type bool
```

I do not see where I have a bool returned from that `g (x, y)` function.
There maybe a simpler way to write (hey, I am new), but i'd like to understand the logic here.

Comment: Nitpick: `if expression then true else false` is just `expression`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this expression:

```
gf x 1 && gs x 1
```

The `&&` operator takes a boolean value at the left and right, and returns a boolean. But your `gf` and `gs` functions each return a pair of ints. The compiler is telling you that you *have* a pair of ints (`int * int`) but you *need* a boolean (as an operand of the `&&` operator).